# Django - Select items and quantity from pre-created list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I cannot figure out a suitable solution for what I believe is a beginner problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

The website I am building will be used to plan parties. Two types of people will use it, party organizers and party visitors.
The party organizers are able to create a party and select items to be offered to visitors. Items are food and drinks, 1 item = one pizza or one beer.

Users will then be able to confirm participation for the party and select which food and drinks they would like to order and how many. 
I already created authentication and creation of a party.

Now, my issues are this:

1. How can the organizer create a list of items to be offered to the
   visitor?
2. How can the visitor select **both** type of item and quantity?

I have tried with the following code (trimmed down):

**models.py:**

```
class ItemType(models.Model):
    """Create items (food and drinks)."""
    name = models.CharField()

class Party(models.Model):
    """Create a party."""
    organizer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    party_name = models.CharField()
    items_to_be_offered = models.ManyToManyField(ItemType)

class PartyRegistration(models.Model):
    """Register for a party / create party registration."""
    party = models.ForeignKey(Party)
    visitor = models.CharField()
    selected_items = models.ManyToManyField()

class ItemSelection(models.Model):
    """Specify which items and number of items the visitor selected."""
    party_registration = models.OneToOneField(PartyRegistration)
    item_type = models.ManyToManyField(ItemType)
    item_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class VisitorRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Form to register a visitor."""

    class Meta:
        model = PartyRegistration
        fields = ['visitor', 'selected_items']
```

**views.py**

```
def VisitorRegister(request, pk):
    """Register Visitor to a specific party."""    
    party = get_object_or_404(Party, pk=pk)    

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VisitorRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name_clean = form.cleaned_data['visitor']
            registration = PartyRegistration(party=party, visitor=name_clean)
            registration.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        form = VisitorRegisterForm()

    context = {'form': form, 'party': party}

    return render(request, 'visitor-register.html', context)
```

Website is Django 2.0, PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a ManyToMany relationship with a `through` model in this case (order matters, or change the order and quote `PartyRegistration`):

```
class PartyRegistration(models.Model):
    """Register for a party / create party registration."""
    party = models.ForeignKey(Party)
    visitor = models.CharField()
    selected_items = models.ManyToManyField(ItemType, through='ItemSelection')

class ItemSelection(models.Model):
    """Specify which items and number of items the visitor selected."""
    party_registration = models.ForeignKey(PartyRegistration)
    item_type = models.ForeignKey(ItemType)
    item_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('party_registration', 'item_type')
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I looked into the documentation and set up the project as recommended. Still, I am not sure how this solves the problem with selecting type and quantity on a single website. 
How can the user simultaneously edit multiple objects (from ItemSelection) in ManyToManyField? Forms allow creating and editing a single object, would formsets be applicable here?

Comment: Yes, formsets are meant for this. You can, of course, use multiple forms and submit via AJAX, as well. It's your choice. (In the Django Admin, you would use Inlines which also use formsets underneath.)